# How to merge two arrays using PHP based on index?

Tags: php, arrays

How can i merge these two arrays:

First Array:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 10
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 21
            )

    )
```

Second Array:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 22
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 13
            )

    )
```

I want the result to be:

```
[0][id]=>10
[1][id]=>11
[2][id]=>21
[3][id]=>22
[4][id]=>13
```

Comment: am I right that you want use I from first, then from second,then from first, then from second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array1 = array(
    array('id' => 10),
    array('id' => 21),
);
$array2 = array(
    array('id' => 11),
    array('id' => 22),
    array('id' => 13),
);
$new_array = array();

$length = max(count($array1), count($array2));

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
  if (isset($array1[$i]))
    array_push($new_array, $array1[$i]);
  if (isset($array2[$i]))
    array_push($new_array, $array2[$i]);
}
print_r($new_array);
```

For me this outputs:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 10 )
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 11 )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 21 )
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 22 )
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 13 )
)
```

**Edit:** Used max to optimize it a bit as  RiaD said.
**Edit2:** Forgot to add $ in front of many i variables...

Comment: it's not so good, to calculate count() two times for 1 array, you can use max(count($arr1),count($arr2)) instead